# Junit flow getting stuck on running embedded server

Tags: java, rest, junit

I have created a small application (RestApi) which basically contains an embedded grizzly server. Now I want to test the functionality and for this I am using Junit.

In the test class I am using @BeforeClass for running the embedded server and the @Test for testing the functionality. On running the test class I can see the server getting started but the flow is getting stuck and not reaching method annotated with the @Test.

Test.java

```
public class MyTest {

@BeforeClass
public static void init() {
    try {
        MyApplication.grizzlyServerSetup();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Test
public void testCreateNewBankAccount() {
     // test some functionality.
}
```

And when I am stopping the server the flow reaches the test method and errors out with Connection Refused exception.

Note: Application works perfectly fine when tested with PostMan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to start grizzly server in a separate thread so that it will not block your main thread with tests.

You can do something like this

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() throws Exception {
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            MyApplication.grizzlyServerSetup();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }).run();
}
```

You may also need a tear down method to stop grizzly server

```
@AfterClass
public static void tearDown() throws Exception {
    //whatever stuff you need to do to stop it
}
```

Comment: It was such a basic mistake, don't know why it didn't click me. Anyways thanks !